# ruby-oci8 gem load error with ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit with ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed ruby-oci8 gem, following the [rubydoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-instant-client.md) steps

After completing the installation, when I tried to run **rails s** command it's giving the error message, says:

```
*ERROR: ActiveRecord oracle_enhanced adapter could not load ruby-oci8 library. Please install ruby-oci8 gem. (LoadError)*
```

need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the actual cause for this behavior, but fresh installation of rvm and ruby and the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

works like the magic.

thank you